# Google apps script spreadsheet:error

Tags: google-apps-script

I work for a public school district and have written a script to take data from a Google form response sheet and filter it into separate sheets based on which school the information relates to. Using the tutorial located at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets . The modified script is 1300 lines long (including some explinations) and has been running smoothly up until recently.

The script now returns numerous errors. Most commonly I see errors such as:

"Service timed out: Spreadsheets (line 40, file "Transfer/SortID/Copy/Sort")"

"Service error: Spreadsheets (line 40, file "Transfer/SortID/Copy/Sort")"

The line that is flagged in the error is

"headersRange.setValues([columnNames]);"

I have tried everything that I can think of including creating a new target spreadsheet.

I have included the beginning section of the code below. Again, this script was running great up until recently. (Last time it ran successfully was 5/6)

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
// This is where the data used in this example will be retrieved from:
// https://docs.google.com/a/psdschools.org/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AswYUpTPhetrdFYxUEJZSkxHeVdfSk5pajh3UjYxaUE&usp=drive_web#gid=0
function TransferAndSort() {{
var DATA_SPREADSHEET_ID = "0AswYUpTPhetrdFYxUEJZSkxHeVdfSk5pajh3UjYxaUE"

//update data

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var dataSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DATA_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var dataSheet = dataSs.getSheets()[0];

  // Fetch all the data
  var data = getRowsData(dataSheet);

  // This is the data we want to display
  var columnNames = ["Last Name","First Name", "ID Number", "School", "Date Written", "Purpose", "Requested Route #", "Requested Stop Location", "Type of Student", "Contact Made"];


// Index data by School name
  var dataBySchool = {};
  var schools = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    if (!dataBySchool[rowData.school]) {
      dataBySchool[rowData.school] = [];
      schools.push(rowData.school);
    }
    dataBySchool[rowData.school].push(rowData);
  }

  schools.sort();
  var headerBackgroundColor = dataSheet.getRange(1, 1).getBackgroundColor();
  for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; ++i) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(schools[i]) ||
      ss.insertSheet(schools[i], ss.getSheets().length);
    sheet.clear();
    var headersRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, columnNames.length);
    headersRange.setValues([columnNames]);
    headersRange.setBackgroundColor(headerBackgroundColor);
    setRowsData(sheet, dataBySchool[schools[i]]);
  }
}

// setRowsData fills in one row of data per object defined in the objects Array.
// For every Column, it checks if data objects define a value for it.
// Arguments:
//   - sheet: the Sheet Object where the data will be written
//   - objects: an Array of Objects, each of which contains data for a row
//   - optHeadersRange: a Range of cells where the column headers are defined. This
//     defaults to the entire first row in sheet.
//   - optFirstDataRowIndex: index of the first row where data should be written. This
//     defaults to the row immediately below the headers.
function setRowsData(sheet, objects, optHeadersRange, optFirstDataRowIndex) {
  var headersRange = optHeadersRange || sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
  var firstDataRowIndex = optFirstDataRowIndex || headersRange.getRowIndex() + 1;
  var headers = normalizeHeaders(headersRange.getValues()[0]);

  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
    var values = []
    for (j = 0; j < headers.length; ++j) {
      var header = headers[j];
      // If the header is non-empty and the object value is 0...
      if ((header.length > 0) && (objects[i][header] == 0)) {
        values.push(0);
      }
      // If the header is non-empty or the object value is empty...
      else if ((!(header.length > 0)) || (objects[i][header]=='')) {
        values.push('');
      }
      else {
        values.push(objects[i][header]);
      }
    }
    data.push(values);
  }

  var destinationRange = sheet.getRange(firstDataRowIndex, headersRange.getColumnIndex(),
                                        objects.length, headers.length);
  destinationRange.setValues(data);
}

// getRowsData iterates row by row in the input range and returns an array of objects.
// Each object contains all the data for a given row, indexed by its normalized column name.
// Arguments:
//   - sheet: the sheet object that contains the data to be processed
//   - range: the exact range of cells where the data is stored
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to all the cells except those in the first row
//       or all the cells below columnHeadersRowIndex (if defined).
//   - columnHeadersRowIndex: specifies the row number where the column names are stored.
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to the row immediately above range;
// Returns an Array of objects.
function getRowsData(sheet, range, columnHeadersRowIndex) {
  var headersIndex = columnHeadersRowIndex || range ? range.getRowIndex() - 1 : 1;
  var dataRange = range ||
    sheet.getRange(headersIndex + 1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows() - headersIndex, sheet.getMaxColumns());
  var numColumns = dataRange.getEndColumn() - dataRange.getColumn() + 1;
  var headersRange = sheet.getRange(headersIndex, dataRange.getColumn(), 1, numColumns);
  var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
  return getObjects(dataRange.getValues(), normalizeHeaders(headers));
}

// For every row of data in data, generates an object that contains the data. Names of
// object fields are defined in keys.
// Arguments:
//   - data: JavaScript 2d array
//   - keys: Array of Strings that define the property names for the objects to create
function getObjects(data, keys) {
  var objects = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var object = {};
    var hasData = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
      var cellData = data[i][j];
      if (isCellEmpty(cellData)) {
        continue;
      }
      object[keys[j]] = cellData;
      hasData = true;
    }
    if (hasData) {
      objects.push(object);
    }
  }
  return objects;
}

// Returns an Array of normalized Strings.
// Empty Strings are returned for all Strings that could not be successfully normalized.
// Arguments:
//   - headers: Array of Strings to normalize
function normalizeHeaders(headers) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i) {
    keys.push(normalizeHeader(headers[i]));
  }
  return keys;
}

// Normalizes a string, by removing all alphanumeric characters and using mixed case
// to separate words. The output will always start with a lower case letter.
// This function is designed to produce JavaScript object property names.
// Arguments:
//   - header: string to normalize
// Examples:
//   "First Name" -> "firstName"
//   "Market Cap (millions) -> "marketCapMillions
//   "1 number at the beginning is ignored" -> "numberAtTheBeginningIsIgnored"
function normalizeHeader(header) {
  var key = "";
  var upperCase = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < header.length; ++i) {
    var letter = header[i];
    if (letter == " " && key.length > 0) {
      upperCase = true;
      continue;
    }
    if (!isAlnum(letter)) {
      continue;
    }
    if (key.length == 0 && isDigit(letter)) {
      continue; // first character must be a letter
    }
    if (upperCase) {
      upperCase = false;
      key += letter.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      key += letter.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return key;
}

// Returns true if the cell where cellData was read from is empty.
// Arguments:
//   - cellData: string
function isCellEmpty(cellData) {
  return typeof(cellData) == "string" && cellData == "";
}

// Returns true if the character char is alphabetical, false otherwise.
function isAlnum(char) {
  return char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z' ||
    char >= 'a' && char <= 'z' ||
    isDigit(char);
}

// Returns true if the character char is a digit, false otherwise.
function isDigit(char) {
  return char >= '0' && char <= '9';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a great answer for you, but this might help or at least offer a little bit of insight.  I'm experiencing similar problems with an add-on that I'm developing.  The issue seems to be related to calling sheet.clear().  After a sheet.clear(), certain operations take a long time the first time they are called.  In our case, we're seeing sheet.getMaxColumns() take upwards of 20s after calling sheet.clear(), whereas it takes only milliseconds if we remove the sheet.clear() call.  If I call it twice in a row, the first call takes a long time, but the second call is very fast again.  I have confirmed that the same behavior is true even if switching to sheet.clearContents().

I'm hoping this is some sort of bug recently introduced by Google that will be addressed quickly, as we don't really have a workaround to calling sheet.clear() at this point in time.

Hope this helps, and good luck!